# Dynamic Range for Average Calculation

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to come up with an Excel Formula to calculate 6 Months average value from Monthly prices.
A year is considered from April 2022 to March 2023 and so on. That means from April 2022 to Sept 2022 it is Half 1 and Oct 2022 to Mar 2023 it is Half 2.
Total time line is till **March 2055**. So, the formula has to be dynamic.

Please advise how I can use a formula for this averaging task.
The Data table look like below.

**INPUT**
Please refer the link to picture

**OUTPUT**
In Yellow in the picture below

[Table Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkJPl.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be fairly simple if we had 'regular' half-year periods. Since half-years are shifted 3 months forward, we also need to shift the formula by three months. To achieve that, we have an OFFSET function that we can apply for the prices row. It will work fine for all the half-year periods with the exception of the first one since we'll have the prices range shifted. So, for the first half of 2022 in the cell B9 we will simply write `=AVERAGE(B5:G5)` and for all the rest, starting from C9, -

```
=AVERAGEIFS(OFFSET($B$5:$OG$5,0,3),$B$1:$OG$1,C7,$B$2:$OG$2, IF(C8=1,"<="&6,">"&6))
```

assuming that the months start in column B like in your example picture and finish in column OG as suggested from your task description.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion works perfectly well. However, can you please explain the purpose of using OFFSET here? We could manually enter the modified range.

Comment: That's true. We could shift it manually and have ($E$5:$OJ$5) instead of OFFSET(). I just thought it's more proper if we use the same column range. Matter of preference, probably.

Answer (score 0):

If you want rolling 6mo periods, I prefer `INDIRECT` to `OFFSET`.

Assume the data runs vertically, each month is a separate row, and "X" is the cell of the latest value, this should work:

`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(x), COLUMN(X))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(X)-5, COLUMN(X))))`